Proof:$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\pi_n(GL(H))=0\Longrightarrow GL(H) \text{ is contractible}$
I'm currently working myself through the proof of Kuiper's Theorem, stating that $GL(H)$ is contractible. The course of action is to first prove that all homotopy groups of $GL(H)$ vanish. Now I want to follow that $GL(H)$ is contractible. I want to show that $GL(H)$ is homtopy equivalent to a CW complex (in specific the nerv of a certain covering) and then use Whitehead's theorem to prove the contractibility. To prove that $GL(H)$ is homotopy equivalent to a certain Nerv of a covering, I've written out a proof, but I think the part where I show that $\sigma\circ\varphi$ is homotope to $id_N$, is wrong, in particular the equation
$\sigma(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_iz_{j_i})
=\sum_{i=1}^N\phi_{j_i}(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_iz_{j_i}))b_{j_i}$
Could you please help me with this small detail of the proof. Either you could explain to me, why this line is true, or suggest a different strategy. Thanks for your time. In the following you see the whole proof:
Since $GL(\mathcal{H}) \subseteq B$ is open, we can cover $GL(\mathcal{H})$ with open balls $U_j:=\{z\in B:\|z-z_j\|<\varepsilon_j\}$ of radius at most 1, each entirely contained in $GL(\mathcal{H})$. We require that these balls with triple the radius also remain fully contained within $GL(\mathcal{H})$. Because $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is paracompact, there exists a locally finite partition of unity subordinate to this covering. This means that there are real continuous functions $\phi_j:GL(\mathcal{H})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\phi_j\geq 0,\:\:\:\sum_{j\in J}\phi_j=1
\end{equation*}
and $V_j:= \text{support}\:\phi_j=\{z\in GL(\mathcal{H}):\phi_j(z)\neq 0\}$ is contained in some ball $U_j$. Because the refinement $\left(V_j\right)_{j\in J}$  is locally finite, every point $z\in GL(\mathcal{H})$ has a neighborhood which meets at most a finite number of supports.\
Let $N$ be the nerve of the covering by the supports $V_j$. Call the vertex that corresponds to $V_j$, $b_j$. Now we prove that $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is homotopy equivalent to $GL(\mathcal{H})$. We define
\begin{align*}
\sigma:GL(\mathcal{H})&\rightarrow N \\
z&\mapsto\sum_{j\in J}\phi_j(z)b_j
\end{align*}
This map is well-defined: The sum $\sum_{j\in J}\phi_j(z)b_j$ is finite because the refinement $\left(V_j\right)$ is locally finite. So we can write
\begin{equation*}
\sigma(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{n_z}\phi_{j_i}b_{j_i}
\end{equation*}
with all $V_{j_i}$ containing $z$. By the definition of a nerve, all $b_{j_i}$ lie in the same simplex. Since simpleces are convex and $\sigma(z)$ is just a convex combination, we obtain $\sigma(z)\in N$. We also notice, that $\sigma$ is continuous since the sum is finite and all $\phi_j$'s are continuous. We also define the continuous map
\begin{align*}
\varphi : N \rightarrow GL(\mathcal{H}) \text{ with }
\begin{cases}
&\varphi(b_j) = z_j \text{ for all } j \in J, \\
&\text{the restriction of } \varphi \text{ to any simplex of } N \text{ is an affine map}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This map is also well defined: Let $\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_ib_{j_i}\in N$ with $\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_i=1$,:$\lambda_i\geq 0$ and all $b_{j_i}$'s being from the same simplex. Then the intersect of all $U_{j_i}$ is non empty. Next we choose the Ball $U$ with largest radius out of all the balls $U_{i_j}$ and obtain that all $U_{j_i}\subseteq 3U$. Here $3U$ denotes the Ball $U$ with triple the radius. Since $3U$ is convex and contained in $GL(\mathcal{H})$ we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_ib_{j_i})=\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_iz_{j_i}\in 3U\subseteq GL(\mathcal{H})
\end{equation*}
With $\sigma:GL(\mathcal{H})\rightarrow N$ and $\varphi : N \rightarrow GL(\mathcal{H})$, we can now, show that $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is homotopy equivalent to $N$.  We define a homotpy leading from $id_N$ to $\sigma\circ\varphi$
\begin{align*}
H:[0,1]\times N&\rightarrow N\\
(t,x)&\mapsto (1-t)x+t\:\sigma(\varphi(x))
\end{align*}
It's well defined: Let $x=\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_ib_{j_i}\in N$ with $\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_i=1$, $\lambda_i\geq 0$ and all $b_{j_i}$'s being from the same simplex. Then
\begin{align*}
\sigma(\varphi(x))=&\sigma(\varphi(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_ib_{j_i})))\\
&=\sigma(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_iz_{j_i})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^N\phi_{j_i}(\sum_{i=0}^N\lambda_iz_{j_i}))b_{j_i}
\end{align*}
So $\sigma(\varphi(x))$  lies in the same simplex as $x$, hence the convex combination $(1-t)x + t\:\sigma(\varphi(x))$ is also in this simplex and therefore in $N$.
We can also define a similar homotopy leading from $id_{GL(\mathcal{H})}$ to $\varphi\circ\sigma$.
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{H}:[0,1]\times GL(\mathcal{H})&\rightarrow GL(\mathcal{H})\\
(t,z)&\mapsto (1-t)z+t\:\varphi(\sigma(z))
\end{align*}
We will again explain that this homotopy is well defined, meaning $\widetilde{H}(t,z)\in GL(\mathcal{H})$.
First notice that
\begin{align*}
\varphi(\sigma(z))&=\varphi(\sum_{j\in J}\phi_j(z)b_j)\\
&=\sum_{j\in J}\phi_j(z)z_j
\end{align*}
This sum is finite and with a similar argument to why $\varphi(x)\in GL(\mathcal{H})$ using the convexity of the $3U$ Ball we've shown that $\widetilde{H}(t,z)\in GL(\mathcal{H})$. In summary we have seen that $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is homotopy equivalent to $N$. Since all homotpy groups of $GL(\mathcal{H})$ vanish, the homotpy groups of $N$ also vanish. Since $N$ is a CW complex, it follows with Whitehead's theorem that $N$ is contractible. Therefore $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is also contractible.
